# follow camera in phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have just figured out how to load a tilemap that I have created in the program tiled and it works as expected so then I am trying to add a player with a basic follow camera using some code from the example but I have nothing happening except the is viewing the middle of the tilemap now here is the code I have tried:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {

    //  Tilemaps are split into two parts: The actual map data (usually stored in a CSV or JSON file) 
    //  and the tileset/s used to render the map.

    //  Here we'll load the tilemap data. The first parameter is a unique key for the map data.

    //  The second is a URL to the JSON file the map data is stored in. This is actually optional, you can pass the JSON object as the 3rd
    //  parameter if you already have it loaded (maybe via a 3rd party source or pre-generated). In which case pass 'null' as the URL and
    //  the JSON object as the 3rd parameter.

    //  The final one tells Phaser the foramt of the map data, in this case it's a JSON file exported from the Tiled map editor.
    //  This could be Phaser.Tilemap.CSV too.

    game.load.tilemap('gameMap', 'assets/tilemaps/gameMap2.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);

    //  Next we load the tileset. This is just an image, loaded in via the normal way we load images:

    game.load.image('tiles', 'assets/tilemaps/gameMap.png');
    game.load.image('player','assets/img/player.gif');
}

var map;
var layer;
var player;
var cursors;

function create() {

    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#787878';
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 3200, 3200);
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'player');


        game.physics.p2.enable(player);

        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        game.camera.follow(player);

    //  The 'mario' key here is the Loader key given in game.load.tilemap
    map = game.add.tilemap('gameMap');

    //  The first parameter is the tileset name, as specified in the Tiled map editor (and in the tilemap json file)
    //  The second parameter maps this name to the Phaser.Cache key 'tiles'
    map.addTilesetImage('spritesheet', 'tiles');

    //  Creates a layer from the World1 layer in the map data.
    //  A Layer is effectively like a Phaser.Sprite, so is added to the display list.
    layer = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');

    //  This resizes the game world to match the layer dimensions
    layer.resizeWorld();

}
function update() {

        player.body.setZeroVelocity();

        if (cursors.up.isDown)
        {
            player.body.moveUp(300)
        }
        else if (cursors.down.isDown)
        {
            player.body.moveDown(300);
        }

        if (cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.x = -300;
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            player.body.moveRight(300);
        }

    }
    function render() {

            game.debug.cameraInfo(game.camera, 32, 32);
            game.debug.spriteCoords(player, 32, 500);

        }
```

I am new to using phaser and I am not sure why this is not working any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the character's functionality and follow-up of the camera after having implemented the creation of the map in this way:

```
function create() {

   //Configure physical engine
   game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

   //Creating the tilemap
   game.stage.backgroundColor = '#787878';

   map = game.add.tilemap('mario');

   map.addTilesetImage('SuperMarioBros-World1-1', 'tiles');

   layer = map.createLayer('World1');

   layer.resizeWorld();

   //Configure player controls
   cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

   //Player creation
   player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'player');

   game.physics.p2.enable(player);

   game.camera.follow(player);

}
```

I have used this [**example**](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/mario) as a basis: